# HTML & React JS: CSS design position problems. ( Content stuck in the corner )

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with some components that should appear in the top right corner of the navbar. I'm pretty much just following a tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF6k0uZuypA&t=302s). So basically the components are spawned in the top left corner, and they stack upon each other, what's the reason for that?

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
:root {
    --bg: #242526;
    --bg-accent: #484a4d;
    --text-color: #dadce1;
    --nav-size: 60px;
    --border: 1px solid #474a4d;
    --border-radius: 8px;
    --speed: 500ms;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    color: var(--text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
    height: var(--nav-size);
    background-color: var(--bg);
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-radius: var(--border);
}

.navbar-nav {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;

}

.nav-item{
    width: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.8);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.icon-button{
    --buton-size: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.5);
    width: var(--button-size);
    height: var(--button-size);
    background-color: #484a4d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    max-resolution: 2px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

React Js (JSX included):

```
function NavItem(props){
    return (
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a href="#" className="icon-button">
                { props.icon }
            </a>
        </li>
    );
}

function Navbar(props) {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar">
            <ul className="navbar-nav"> { props.children } </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Fragment>
                    <Navbar>
                        <NavItem icon="" />
                        <NavItem icon="" />
                        <NavItem icon="" />
                    </Navbar>
                    <div className="container">
                        <Dashboard/>
                    </div>
                </Fragment>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

This is what I get while rendering:

[image]

This is what I should get:
[image]

Generated HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Lead Manager</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
      <style></style>
      <style>:root {
         --bg: #242526;
         --bg-accent: #484a4d;
         --text-color: #dadce1;
         --nav-size: 60px;
         --border: 1px solid #474a4d;
         --border-radius: 8px;
         --speed: 500ms;
         }
         ul{
         list-style: none;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         }
         a {
         color: var(--text-color);
         text-decoration: none;
         }
         .navbar {
         height: var(--nav-size);
         background-color: var(--bg);
         padding: 0 1rem;
         border-radius: var(--border);
         }
         .navbar-nav {
         max-width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         display: flex;
         justify-content: flex-end;
         }
         .nav-item{
         width: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.8);
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         }
         .icon-button{
         --buton-size: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.5);
         width: var(--button-size);
         height: var(--button-size);
         background-color: #484a4d;
         border-radius: 50%;
         padding: 5px;
         max-resolution: 2px;
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="app">
         <nav class="navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="icon-button"></a></li>
               <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="icon-button"></a></li>
               <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="icon-button"></a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

- EDIT! : I have added text-center bootstrap in-built class element to the navbar class and I got this result:

[image]

- Note! : Text-right doesn't make the text flex in right

Comment: You may want to add the generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it with:

```
.navbar-nav{
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction:row-reverse;
    justify-content: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```css
ul{
  /* ... */
  display: flex;
  float: right;
}
.navbar {
  /* ... */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using flex

```
<style>
    .navbar-nav{
                 display:flex;
                 flex:1;
                 flex-direction:row-reverse
               }
</style>
```

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: @DzITC are you sure? do you change .navbar-nav css class to above codes? i test your codes and change .navbar-nav css class to above codes then i got the result that you want